# Area of ellipse $\frac{x^2}{a^2}+ \frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{xy}{ab}-\frac{x}{a}-\frac{y}{b}=0$

Tags: conic-sections, area

Is someone able to help me with this question?

For a>0, b>0, find the area of the area D delimited by the ellipse

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+ \frac{y^2}{b^2}+\frac{xy}{ab}-\frac{x}{a}-\frac{y}{b}=0$$

by doing a change of variable:
$$ \frac{x}{a}= Au+Bv$$ and $$\frac{y}{b}=Cu+Dv$$

I dont know how to start attacking this problem, any help would be very appreciated. Thanks a lot! By the way,English is not my first langage so sorry if there is any mistakes.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)

Comment: Thanks for the tip!

Comment: Have you tried simply substituting for $x/a$ and $y/b$ in the original equation and then trying to work out what the unknown coefficients in the change of variables must be?

Comment: You can use three facts: 1- area of ellipse = pi* semi-major *semi-minor axis  2: make a change of variable so that the cross term disappears  so that you can get the axes 3: area changes by determinant of transformation ( Jacobian)

Answer (score 2):

Re-center and rescale the ellipse with  $x=a(t+\frac13)$ and $y=b(s+\frac13)$,

$$t^2+ts+s^2 = \frac13$$

Then, rotate with $t=\frac1{\sqrt2}(u+v)$ and $s=\frac1{\sqrt2}(u-v)$,

$$\frac{u^2}{\frac29}+\frac{v^2}{\frac23} = 1$$

Therefore, the area of the ellipse is

$$A= ab\pi \sqrt{\frac29\cdot\frac23}=\frac{2\sqrt3\pi}9ab$$